# Reverse String Word by Word using SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I would need to reverse the word positions in a sentence or String.

```
For example : "Hello World! I Love StackOverflow", to be displayed as "StackOverflow Love I World! Hello".
```

Can it be done with a `SQL` ? The word length is no greater than `VARCHAR2(4000)` which is the maximum length support in a Oracle `VARCHAR2` table column.

I got solutions for reversing a string (Characters in reverse order) only

Comment: you could write a PL/SQL function, and use it in SQL directly.

Comment: Its relatively easy to search for the next instance of a space and using that do some string manipulation with a function. What have you tried ?

Comment: an interesting homework problem, your instructor was probably trying to teach you about using collections or cursors, or to see how clever you are.  I guess copy/pasting from SO is clever too ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Create a **Function**:*

`REGEXP_SUBSTR('Your text here','[^ ]+', 1, ?)` will extract a word from the text using Space as a delimiter. Tt returns the original String itself on Exception!

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION reverse_words (v_STRING IN VARCHAR2)
RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
   L_TEMP_TEXT  VARCHAR2(4000);
   L_FINAL_TEXT  VARCHAR2(4000);
   V_LOOPCOUNT NUMBER :=0;
   T_WORD VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
      L_TEMP_TEXT := regexp_replace(V_STRING,'[[:space:]]+',' '); -- Replace multiple spaces as single
      LOOP
        v_LOOPCOUNT := v_LOOPCOUNT+1;
        T_WORD      := REGEXP_SUBSTR(L_TEMP_TEXT,'[^ ]+', 1, V_LOOPCOUNT);
        L_final_TEXT := T_WORD||' '||L_final_TEXT;
      EXIT WHEN T_WORD IS NULL;
      END LOOP;
   RETURN(TRIM(L_final_TEXT));
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(sqlerrm||chr(10)||dbms_utility.format_error_backtrace);
        RETURN V_STRING;
END reverse_words;
/
```

***Sample Result:***

You can call `reverse_words(yourcolumn) from your_table`

```
SQL> select reverse_words('Hello World! I Love StackOverflow') "Reversed" from dual;

Reversed
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
StackOverflow Love I World! Hello
```

Answer (score 9):

XML-based version to avoid defining your own function; requires 11g for `listagg()`:

```
select listagg(word, ' ') within group (order by rn desc) as reversed
from (
  select word, rownum as rn
  from xmltable('for $i in ora:tokenize($STR, " ") return $i'
    passing 'Hello World! I Love StackOverflow' as str
    columns word varchar2(4000) path '.'
  )
);

REVERSED                               
----------------------------------------
StackOverflow Love I World! Hello
```

The `XMLTable()` does the tokenising, and assigns a row number:

```
select rownum as rn, word
from xmltable('for $i in ora:tokenize($STR, " ") return $i'
  passing 'Hello World! I Love StackOverflow' as str
  columns word varchar2(4000) path '.'
);

        RN WORD               
---------- --------------------
         1 Hello                
         2 World!               
         3 I                    
         4 Love                 
         5 StackOverflow
```

The `listagg()` then pieces it back together in reverse order.

Comment: Thanks Alex! I never heard xmltable and I get your approach. Sorry am a novice! For now I go with a custom function, as it suits me better!

Answer (score 3):

Here you go:

```
WITH sel_string AS 
      (SELECT 'Hello World! I Love StackOverflow' AS fullstring FROM DUAL)
  SELECT SUBSTR(fullstring, beg + 1, end_p - beg - 1) AS token
    FROM (SELECT beg, LEAD(beg) OVER (ORDER BY beg) AS end_p, fullstring
            FROM (SELECT beg, fullstring
                    FROM (SELECT LEVEL beg, fullstring
                            FROM sel_string
                            CONNECT BY LEVEL <= LENGTH(fullstring))
                    WHERE INSTR(' ', SUBSTR(fullstring, beg, 1)) > 0
                  UNION ALL
                    SELECT 0, fullstring FROM sel_string
                  UNION ALL
                    SELECT LENGTH(fullstring) + 1, fullstring FROM sel_string))
    WHERE end_p IS NOT NULL AND
          end_p > beg + 1
    ORDER BY ROWNUM DESC;
```

All in one SQL query. I wish I could claim credit for this query but I can't - found it years ago on the net and have used it ever since.

Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 3):

One more solution

```
WITH str_tab(str1, rn) AS
(SELECT regexp_substr(str, '[^\[:space:]]+', 1, LEVEL), 
        LEVEL 
   FROM (SELECT 'Hello World! I Love StackOverflow' str
           FROM dual) tab
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= LENGTH(str) - LENGTH(REPLACE(str, ' ')) + 1)
SELECT listagg(str1, ' ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY rn DESC) AS new_text
  FROM str_tab;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE 

in_string VARCHAR2(500);
pros_string  VARCHAR2(500);
out_string  VARCHAR2(800);  
spce_cnt NUMBER;


BEGIN

in_string := 'Hello World! I Love StackOverflow';
pros_string := ' '||in_string||' ' ;   
spce_cnt := REGEXP_COUNT(pros_string,' ',1);
FOR i IN reverse  1.. spce_cnt-1  
LOOP                               
 out_string := out_string||' '|| SubStr (pros_string,InStr(pros_string, ' ',1,i)+1 ,InStr(SubStr (pros_string,InStr(pros_string, ' ',1,i)+1 ),' '  ));    
Dbms_Output.Put_Line(out_string);    
END LOOP; 
END;
```