# Is there a group limit for Regep_replace in Oracle? (with regexp_replace issue)

Tags: regex, oracle, oracle11g, substring, reverse

At the moment I got a long input string that I want to reverse with regexp_replace. Normally I replace a strings position by using this (from within the begin clause in PL/SQL)

```
variable:= regexp_replace(variable, '(.+) (.+) (.+) (.+)', '\4 \3 \2 \1');
```

In this case my variabele will be replaced in a reversed order, and it works. Now my problem and my question is. Is there a limit in making groups? Because I got this string:

```
US 816909877808647715885542447721 UOPX
```

I put this string as input into my function and the function begins to transform this string. At a certain point it makes group of four (which is working as well). For this I am using the following:

```
variable:= regexp_replace(variable, '(....)', '\1 ');
```

which results in the next output:

```
3630 3139 3634 8169 0987 7808 6477 1588 5542 4477 21 -- also did ASCII to number
```

so at the moment I got exactly what I want. The whole string is divided into groups of four. But now my problem is, when I want to reverse all these 11 groups with this code:

```
  convertedStudentNumber := regexp_replace(convertedStudentNumber, '(.+) (.+) (.+) (.+) (.+) (.+) (.+) (.+) (.+) (.+) (.+)', '\11 \10 \9 \8 \7 \6 \5 \4 \3 \2 \1');
```

this is my result:

```
36301 36300 5542 1588 6477 7808 0987 8169 3634 3139 3630
```

and when I do reversing groups with 9 groups as follow:

```
  variable:= regexp_replace(variable, '(.+) (.+) (.+) (.+) (.+) (.+) (.+) (.+) (.+)', '\9 \8 \7 \6 \5 \4 \3 \2 \1');
```

this is my result:

```
21 4477 5542 1588 6477 7808 0987 8169 3630 3139 3634
```

with the 9 groups I get's closer to what I want to achieve. But still the last three groups are unable to be fixed in some strange way.

```
21 4477 5542 1588 6477 7808 0987 8169 [3630 3139 3634]--won't work.
```

In short. This is my string that I want to reverse by groups

```
3630 3139 3634 8169 0987 7808 6477 1588 5542 4477 21
```

but I am not getting further than

```
21 4477 5542 1588 6477 7808 0987 8169 [3630 3139 3634]
```

Comment: This doesn't seem like a duplicate to me.  I think the question is asking for help solving the problem, not just "Oracle backreferences only go up to 9".

Comment: Maybe you could split your string into a group of four and a group of five, reverse each group, and stick the groups back together in, also in reverse order? Otherwise you could tokenise it and listagg them back together.

Comment: @AlexPoole, I was going to propose a similar solution but can't because the question is closed.

Comment: @MarkLeiber - the only question is in the title, and that is a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1564981/is-it-possible-to-refer-to-a-10th-and-subsequent-replacement-strings-in-oracles) really. and explains what the OP is seeing. But I take your point, and if you have an answer ready to go I'll reopen.

Comment: @AlexPoole, thanks. I added my answer. Feel free to close if you think there's no additional value. At least the user has something that might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle only allows 9 backreferences so you won't be able to use \10 or higher.
However, why not take your string and reverse each of the groups?

For example:

```
create table test (
   v varchar(100)
);

insert into test values ('363031393634816909877808647715885542447721');

select v, regexp_replace(v, '([0-9]{4})', '\1 ') as v_replaced
from test;
```

Result:

```
3630 3139 3634 8169 0987 7808 6477 1588 5542 4477 21
```

Now reverse the order of each number group (technique taken from here: [Reverse String Word by Word using SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20973874/reverse-string-word-by-word-using-sql)):

```
WITH str_tab(str1, rn) AS
(SELECT regexp_substr(str, '[^\[:space:]]+', 1, LEVEL), 
        LEVEL 
   FROM (SELECT regexp_replace(v, '([0-9]{4})', '\1 ') str
           FROM test) tab
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= LENGTH(str) - LENGTH(REPLACE(str, ' ')) + 1)
SELECT listagg(str1, ' ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY rn DESC) AS new_text
  FROM str_tab;
```

Result:

```
21 4477 5542 1588 6477 7808 0987 8169 3634 3139 3630
```

Here is the same thing in a PL/SQL script:

```
declare
  variable varchar(100) := '363031393634816909877808647715885542447721';
begin
  -- You don't need these next two lines.
  -- They just show you the variable modified to have a space
  -- after every four digits.  You can remove these lines.
  variable := regexp_replace(variable, '([0-9]{4})', '\1 ');
  dbms_output.put_line('variable: ' || variable);

  -- Get the reversed string INTO the variable
  WITH str_tab(str1, rn) AS
  (SELECT regexp_substr(str, '[^\[:space:]]+', 1, LEVEL),  LEVEL 
   FROM (SELECT regexp_replace(variable, '([0-9]{4})', '\1 ') str FROM test) tab
   CONNECT BY LEVEL <= LENGTH(str) - LENGTH(REPLACE(str, ' ')) + 1)
   SELECT listagg(str1, ' ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY rn DESC) AS new_text
   INTO variable
   FROM str_tab;

  dbms_output.put_line('variable: ' || variable);
end;
```

CONNECT BY LEVEL defines the relationship between the parent and child rows in a hierarchy. To understand it, take a look at the Hierarchical Query Examples in the documentation on Hierarchical Queries: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries003.htm

Try running this query:

```
SELECT regexp_substr(str, '[^\[:space:]]+', 1, LEVEL) number_group,  LEVEL 
FROM (SELECT regexp_replace('363031393634816909877808647715885542447721', '([0-9]{4})', '\1 ') str FROM test)
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= LENGTH(str) - LENGTH(REPLACE(str, ' ')) + 1;
```

Result:

```
NUMBER_GROUP  LEVEL
3630          1
3139          2
3634          3
8169          4
0987          5
7808          6
6477          7
1588          8
5542          9
4477          10
21            11
```

The `LENGTH(str)` is the length of the string (after putting in the spaces), which is 52.  `LENGTH(REPLACE(str, ' '))` is the length with the spaces removed, which is 42.  If you take (52-42)+1 you get 11, which is the number of rows we need for all of the number groupings.  Then we just take that list in DESC order and use LISTAGG (with a space as the delimiter) to reassemble the string.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I tried to brake down the code, but it's too difficult for me. Sorry. Could there be an easier way? What confused me is the "connect by level" as "within group". Is there a way to do this without creating a table and without a select statement? ps: I am new towith PL/SQL. If I ask too much from you I can understand. Cheers

Comment: You don't need to create a table. I did that just to show where I was getting a value from. In my example, v is the same as your "variable". Are you selecting that out of a table, getting it as an input parameter to a procedure, or something else?

Comment: The string value is from a testcase. It does not come from a table, procedure, function or any other. The test case with the multiple strings is to check if the function that I am making can validate the test case strings. I already have a function and within that function I need to make groups of four and after that reverse the words (and many more..) but I am stuck with reversing

Comment: @MaximedeLange, I updated my answer with a PL/SQL block for you and more explanation about how the query works.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. Got it fixed. Thanks again, and I mark your awnser as the right given one. Cheers